# Multivariate normal distribution using some variable multiple times

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

short question. If $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ is multivariate normal distributed can I also conclude that $(X,Y,X)$ is normal distributed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, the Gaussian distribution is stable by linear map.